# index out of bounds exception, apache poi sheets, java program

Tags: java, apache-poi, indexoutofboundsexception

So I'm referencing 2 array list to a function so that the elements can be written to an excel worksheet:

the sheetCounter is 1 more than the list index

```
public static void writeToSheet(List<String> name, List<Double> salary, int sheetCounter){

        Workbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
        List<Sheet> outputSheets=new ArrayList<>(10);
        outputSheets.add(wb.createSheet("sheet"+sheetCounter));
        for(int i=0;i<salary.size();i++){
            **Row row=outputSheets.get(sheetCounter-1).createRow(i);**

            Cell nameCell=row.createCell(0);
            nameCell.setCellValue(name.get(i));

            Cell salaryCell=row.createCell(1);
            salaryCell.setCellValue(salary.get(i));
        }

        try{ 
            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("newStackOverflow.xlsx");
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However I'm getting a error on the starred line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at additives.StackOverflow.writeToSheet(StackOverflow.java:31)
    at additives.StackOverflow.main(StackOverflow.java:91)
```

How can I fix this?

here the main(...) and readWorkbook(), everything is mainly happening in the nested for loop:

```
public static Workbook readWorkbook(){

        Workbook wb=null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("stackOverflow.xlsx"));
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return wb;
    }


public static void main(String[] args){

        Workbook inputWb=readWorkbook();
        Sheet inputWs=inputWb.getSheet("sheet1");

        List<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> salary=new ArrayList<>();

        int rowIndex=inputWs.getLastRowNum()+1;

        int sheetCounter=0;

        for(int i=1; i<rowIndex-1; i++){
            Row outerRow=inputWs.getRow(i);
            Row innerRow=null; 
            Cell outerCell=outerRow.getCell(0);
            Cell innerCell=null;


            int j=0;
            for(j=i+1;j<rowIndex;j++){

                innerRow=inputWs.getRow(j);
                innerCell=innerRow.getCell(0);

                if(outerCell.getStringCellValue().equals(innerCell.getStringCellValue())){
                    name.add(innerRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                    salary.add(innerRow.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
                }


                if(!outerCell.getStringCellValue().equals(innerCell.getStringCellValue())){
                    sheetCounter++;
                    break;
                }


            }
            System.out.println("the sheet no is="+sheetCounter);
            name.add(outerRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            salary.add(outerRow.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
            System.out.println(name+" "+salary);
            writeToSheet(name,salary,sheetCounter);

            i=j;
            name.add(outerRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            salary.add(outerRow.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
            System.out.println(i);
            name.clear();
            salary.clear();
            System.out.println(name);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't request the second element in an `ArrayList` when there is only one element there.

Comment: but im requesting the first element, hence the sheetCounter-1

Comment: That seems to be giving you a value of `1`. Arrays (and `ArrayList`'s) are 0 based.

Comment: inside the for i even did listCounter=sheetCounter--;
 Row row=outputSheets.get(listCounter).createRow(i);

and when i enter the function the value of sheetCounter is 1, so why is this happening?

Comment: what value you pass for variable sheetCounter ??

Comment: so size of name & salary list is equal or greater then salary.size() ??

Comment: It would really help if you could post a short but *complete* program demonstrating this problem. I'm sure you can cut out a huge amount of the real code, but if you can give us something we can run to reproduce the problem, it'll be much simpler.

Comment: the name and salary list have the same size, if thats what you're asking

Comment: can you paste your complete class.It will be east for ur

Comment: just posted the main, you can check it now :)

Comment: I dnt find any line in main method to call writeToSheet method, also method readWorkbook exist in main method but no such method is pasted here

Comment: check now, i have made the edits, this time everything is there

Comment: **i fixed it, i shouldnt declare the list in the function, i should create it in the main then reference it to the function :)**

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar problem with this exception and what resolved is the format of my excel file. I define the "table" and give the name for it.

[image: Define name of my table]